# How to search filenames by regex with "find" and rename this files

Tags: find, regular-expression

I trying to find all files ending with :

- ancestors-the-humankind-odyssey-trailers-**720-1262**.mp4
- high-tech-divers-**1080-1234**.mp4
- amazon-divers-**720-1323**.mp4

and rename this files like this :

- **720-1262**.mp4
- **1080-1234**.mp4
- **720-1323**.mp4

I use regex but nothing, why ? what's wrong pls ?

```
find . -regex '^.*-(([0-9])*-([0-9])*)\.mp4'
```

Only one directory and these files, no subdirectories. approximately 300 files .mp4

Comment: Files in one particular directory? Or are these files also in subdirectories?

Comment: Approximately how many files are there to search? (10, 1000, 100000,..?)

Comment: @roaima Only one directory and these files, no subdirectories. approximately 300 files .mp4

Comment: Which `find` implementation are you using? The GNU one?

Comment: @fra-san yes GNU findutils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `find` supports several regular expression dialects (the `-regextype` option lets you select one). Parentheses are special characters in some of them and need to be backslash-escaped to gain their special meaning in others.

According to the [online documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Full-Name-Patterns.html#Full-Name-Patterns), the default dialect used by `-regex` is "POSIX basic", while the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) available online says the default dialect is "Emacs"<sup>1</sup>. In both of them parentheses need to be backslash-escaped to work as grouping characters.

These would work:

```bsh
find . -regex '^.*-\(\([0-9]\)*-\([0-9]\)*\)\.mp4'
```

```bsh
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*-(([0-9])*-([0-9])*)\.mp4'
```

However, `^` is not needed here (`-regex` performs a full match on file names) and grouping seems unnecessary; hence

```bsh
find . -regex '.*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*\.mp4'
```

should be enough (setting aside the potential issues relating to collation: `[0-9]` could match more things than `[0123456789]`, depending on your locale).

About renaming: the Perl implementation of `rename`, if available to you, would be a handy option. Assuming all the files to rename are in the current working directory (no need to `find`):

```bsh
perl-rename -nv 's/.*-(\d*-\d*\.mp4)\Z/$1/' -- *
```

(where `\Z` is the equivalent of the `$` of standard regexps to match at the end of the subject<sup>2</sup>).

Remove the `n` (dry-run) option when you feel you are happy with what the command would do.

Note that

- this will also rename `--.mp4` to `-.mp4`: use `\d+` to require at least one digit to appear before and after the last `-`
- `.*` would be needed to also rename hidden files

Alternatively, with GNU `find` and the standard `mv` utility (also descending recursively into subdirectories):

```bsh
find . -regex '.*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*\.mp4' -execdir sh -c '
  for file; do
    toremove=${file%-*-*.mp4}
    echo mv -- "$file" "${file#"$toremove"-}"
  done' mysh {} +
```

Remove the `echo` when you feel you are happy with what the command would do.

---

<sup>¹ As [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) pointed out in comments, a few bug reports have been filed on savannah.org about this inaccuracy/inconsistency in the documentation: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?58384, https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?52592, https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?61304</sup>
<sup>² Perl's `$` matches at the end of the subject, but also before a newline at the end of the subject, so while fine when working on text lines which may or may not contain a delimiter, it's better to use `\Z` when working with anything else such as file names here.</sup>

Comment: See https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?58384 about that documentation bug

Comment: Also https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?52592 and https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?61304

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(**/)*-(<->-<->.mp4)' '$1$2'
```

(remove the `-n` for dry-run if happy).